# bash: convert string to int & if int > #

Tags: string, bash, if-statement, int

I would like to have a bash script that checks if a file has more than # amount of lines but i have not yet got it working right and I'm not so sure on how to do it.
I've never used bash before.

right now i use: `linesStr=$(cat log | wc -l)` to get the amount of lines in the file (expect it to be a string). when echo'ing it gives me the number 30 which is correct.

but since its most likely a string it doesnt do the if-statement, so i need to have linesStr converted into a int called linesInt.

I also have the feeling the if-statement itself is not done correctly either.

```
#!/bin/bash

linesStr=$(cat log | wc -l)
echo $linesStr

if [$linesStr > 29]
    then echo "log file is bigger than 29 lines"
    #sed -i 1d log
fi
```

I would appreciate if anyone can give me a simple beginners solution.

Comment: You can just do `wc -l < log`.

Comment: wc  -l < log returns "30 log"  and $(cat log | wc -l) just gives "30" so I'd prefer to use that instead

Comment: Sorry, that was a bug in my original comment. `wc -l log` prints `30 log`, but `wc -l < log` just prints `30`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. No need for `cat`.
2. Lack of spaces around `[` and `]`.
3. Use a numeric comparison operator instead of the redirect operator.

Here is a working script.

```
#!/bin/bash

linesStr=$( wc -l < log )

if [[ "$linesStr" -gt "29" ]]; then
    echo Foo
fi
```

Comment: No need for `awk`.

Comment: Try it without.

Comment: With your script i get: -bash: test.bash: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
-bash: test.bash: line 15: `fi'

Comment: @HuskerDoggo, It sounds like you copied and pasted some invalid characters. Also how are you running it?

Comment: im just running it with "source test.bash". I just retyped it and it still gives the same errors

Comment: @HuskerDoggo, Try running it with `./test.bash` instead. Actually, I just tested sourcing it and it still works. I think something else is likely wrong. Perhaps your environment is different.

Comment: copied it into a new script and running that with both source and ./ runs it correctly now thank you

Comment: why using awk when you can do something like this `wc -l < log`

Comment: Either with `wc` or with `awk` , we can avoid sub shells and pipes: `awk 'END {print NR}' log` is the same as `wc -l <log` = prints the number of lines directly.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou, Thank you for your suggestions. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

your if block of code is wrong `if [$linesStr > 29]` there should be a space after `[` and before `]`

```
#!/bin/bash

linesStr=$(wc -l < log )
echo $linesStr

if [[ $lineStr -gt 29 ]];then 
    echo "log file is bigger than 29 lines"
fi
```

it is advisable that you always use `[[ ]]` with an if statement rather than using `[ ]`. Whenever you want to compare integers dont use `>` or `<`, use `-gt` `-ge` `-lt` `-le`. And if you want to do any form of mathematical comparison it is advisable that you use `(( ))`.

```
(( lineStr > 29 )) && {
    # do stuff
}
```

you should also note that you don't need the bash comparison operators or getting the value of a variable with `$` when using `(( ))`

Comment: Comparing numbers in bash (man bash - arithmetic evaluation) can be done with ((  )) for hard coded numbers but with variables there is a bug: If one of the variables holds not valid number (i.e text) the result of arithmetic evaluation is incorrect. Test it with : `a=4;b="3";(($a>$b)) && echo "ok" || echo "not ok"` (this works fine) and then repeat the test by assigning `b="asd"`.

Answer (score 1):

There are no string or integer types to convert. The problem is that you're using the wrong comparison operator. For numeric comparison use `if [ $linesStr -gt 29 ]`. Read `man bash` section `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS` for available operators.

Comment: The other problem is that `[` is a command (and `]` is an argument of that command), so you need spaces around `[` and `]`. `[$linesStr` will try to run a command named `[30`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(( $(wc -l < log) > 29 )) && echo too long
```

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be [preferable to include the essential parts of the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) here, and provide the link for reference.